# Not receiving email from PHP mail() contact form

Tags: php, forms, email, cpanel, contacts

I know this question has been asked countless times but I have been unable to find an answer specific to me.

My contact form seems to be validating perfectly fine and when suitable data is entered and the "send message" button is clicked, a message is displayed saying the message has in fact been sent. There are no error messages on screen.

**My html code looks like this:**

```
<form action="send.php" id="contact_form" method="post" name="contact_form">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>NAME <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" class="requiredField" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>EMAIL <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="requiredField email" />
    </li>
    <li class="textarea">
      <label>MESSAGE <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="20" cols="30" class="requiredField"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="button_form">
      <input name="submitted" id="submitted" value="Send Message" class="submit" type="submit" />
      <input id="reset" type="reset" value="Reset Form" class="submit" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate();
  });
  //]]>
```

**My JS looks like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form#contact_form').submit(function() {
    $('form#contact_form .error').remove();
      var hasError = false;
      $('.requiredField').each(function() {
        if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
          var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
          $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Please enter your '+labelText+'</span>');
          $(this).addClass('inputError');
          hasError = true;
        }
        else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
          var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
          if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
            var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">Please a valid '+labelText+'</span>');
            $(this).addClass('inputError');
            hasError = true;
          }
        }
      });

      if(!hasError) {
        $('form#contact_form input.submit').fadeOut('normal', function() {
          $(this).parent().append('');
        });
        var formInput = $(this).serialize();
        $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
        $('form#contact_form').slideUp("fast", function() {
      $(this).before('<p class="success">Thank you!<br/>Your email was sent successfully.<br/>I will contact you as soon as possible.</p>');
        });
      });
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

**My PHP looks like this:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); // hide all basic notices from PHP

if(!isset($hasError)) {

  $emailTo = 'name@domain.com';
  $subject = 'Submitted message from '.$name;
  $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
  $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments: $comments";
  $headers = 'From: ' .' <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

  mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);


  $emailSent = true;
}
}
?>
```

Am i missing something in the code? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Fyi, disabling `E_NOTICE` is a **bad thing** as most notices mean your code is bad or wrong.

Comment: Are you sending to a hotmail address? Hotmail (and several other mail service providers) seems to block mails from mail(). You probably want to use a mailer class.

Comment: In addition to what ThiefMaster and Sietse have said: check the return value of `mail()` and if possible check your mailserver logs (if sendmail is used).

Comment: Thanks guys, (ThiefMaster I will bear that in mind) ...Yes Sietse I was using a hotmail address but when that didn't work I tried using a googlemail and then @me.com address without any luck. Finally decided to try an email address provided by my web host through my website domain. This didn't do the trick either.

Comment: You're just assuming that the mail queue accepted the message and not checking the return value of mail().  While mail() returning true doesn't mean the mail got sent (it actually only means that the mail transfer subsystem accepted the message as valid), if it returns false it means that it definitely didn't send the message.  Please update your code to check the return value of mail().  If it's false, then there's probably a problem with your script, if it's true then the problem probably lies outside of PHP.

Comment: Remember that $name inside your body is not actually sending the value of that variable, only the name of the variable itself (as well as $email and $comments)

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos why would that be? PHP usually substitutes values for variables inside double-quoted strings just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like "Something".$name." something else"; to be displayed properly?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos That works too. But if you reference a variable inside a double-quoted string, PHP will substitute the value of the variable. Try it and see.

Comment: I didn't know that, will test it, thanks for making me learn something new even in SO comments!

Answer (score 0):

What is the email system used in your server. Do you have sendmail, SMTP etc. I mean whether you checked the mail port (ex:smtp_port) and smtp ip address ("localhost or 192.168.132.1 etc") etc in your php.ini file.

if there is a problem with these settings than your mail won't work. Best is to first check with smtp as its faster than sendmail. You can use google smtp settings for that purpose. 
Check this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server.